# Hash a hexadecimal number with sha-256 in java

Tags: java, hex, sha256

Let's say that I have a big hexadecimal number. Like `"0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE BAAE DCE6 AF48 A03B BFD2 5E8C D036 4139"`. How can I hash it using sha-256 as a hexadecimal(Not Like a normal String) in Java. In the code below the given hexadecimal number has hash as a String. But I want to hash the real hexadecimal number. Not the matching string.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.math.BigInteger;


/**
 *
 * @author Kanchana
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
           String hex = "0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE BAAE DCE6 AF48 A03B BFD2 5E8C D036 4139";
           hex = hex.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
           
           System.out.println("Hash the Hexadecimal number: " + hex);
           
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
           
           md.update(hex.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
           byte[] digest = md.digest();
           
           String hash = String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, digest));
           System.out.println("Hash of the hex: " + hash);
    }
}
```

```
//Current Output
Hash the Hexadecimal number: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364139
Hash of the hex: 6af75a6ef3dc47590c3f8232f7fb4a0905adbb04e045a5616a6533b48365c937
```

```
//Correct Output Should Be
Hash the Hexadecimal number: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364139
Hash of the hex: af30ef0d050f65f9b62099fb4fdd9a8859e95495f0737ab442578ef96d61ceae
```

Comment: Remove the spaces and convert it to `BigInteger`.

Comment: Given you have a 256-bit integer, why do you want to transform it into another 256-bit integer?